# How to take time in and time out in controller and save database (Single table) using Laravel 7 ( Attendance system)

Tags: php, laravel

```php
public function storeActivity(Request $request)   
{
    $request['time']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", time());
    $this->validate($request,[
       'description1' => 'required',
       'description2' => 'nullable',
       'description3' => 'nullable',
       'description4' => 'nullable',
     ]);
     $emp_id = 'ims12933';
     //$punch_in = $request['time']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", time());
     $session_id = $_COOKIE["laravel_session"];
     $post = new activity;
     $post->emp_id = $emp_id;

     $post->punch_in = $request['time']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time());
     $post->punch_date = $request['time']=date("Y-m-d", time());
     $post->sess_id = $session_id;
     $post->description1 = $request->description1;
     $post->description2 = $request->description2;
     $post->description3 = $request->description3;
     $post->description4 = $request->description4;
     $post->save();
     return redirect('home')->with('Successfully', 'Punch In');
}
```

This is I am submitting but can't take time out data in a single table of database.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('planned_activites')
        ->where('sess_id', $sess_id)  // find your user by their email
        ->limit(1)  // optional - to ensure only one record is updated.
        ->update(array('punch_out' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()), 'ip_out' => \Request::getClientIp(true), 'description2' => $request->description2, 'description3' => $request->description3));
```

Mainly update function will update the same table.